# Filling table with data from file on localhost

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have this particular table:

```
<div class="chartHeader"><p>Performance statistics summary</p></div>
<table id="tableSummary">
    <tr>
        <th>Measurement name</th>
        <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total messages sent</td>
        <td id = "totalMessagesSent"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total messages processed</td>
        <td id = "totalMessagesProcessed"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Average messages per second</td>
        <td id = "averageMessagesPerSecond"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Somewhere on the disk I have such json generated in groovy:

```
{
    "reportSummary": {
        "totalMessagesSent": 23,
        "totalMessagesProcessed": 10384,
        "averageMessagesPerSecond": 2.3E-8
    }
}
```

I want to fill that table above with date from that json by using javascript, tried many versions but couldn't make it, in my html page I added:

```
<script type="text/javascript">fillTableWithData('reportSummary.json');</script>
```

And the script is currently like this, but it does not work:

```
  function fillTableWithData(filename) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var jsonFile = reader.readAsText(filename);
    var jsons = d3.json(jsonFile);

    d3.select("#totalMessagesSent").append(jsons.totalMessagesSent);
    d3.select("#totalMessagesProcessed").append(jsons.totalMessagesProcessed);
    d3.select("#averageMessagesPerSecond").append(jsons.averageMessagesPerSecond);
}
```

Could anyone suggest me how to do it properly? I spent way too much time on it and I am currently out of ideas... any help appreciated. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: If it is easier in pure js, I don't need to use d3 here at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to that problem is here:

```
function fillTableWithData(filename) {

var data_file = filename;
var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
try {
    http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e) {
    try {
        http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
http_request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);

        document.getElementById("messagesSent").innerHTML = jsonObj.reportSummary.messagesSent;
        document.getElementById("tradeEventsProcessed").innerHTML = jsonObj.reportSummary.tradeEventsProcessed;
        document.getElementById("averageMessagesPerSecond").innerHTML = jsonObj.reportSummary.averageMessagesPerSecond;
    }
}
http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
http_request.send();
}
```

We can't simply use js to load files as it works on client's side.